# How to get all Controls' ControlTemplates Programmatically?(UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Although I know I can get all ControlTemplates from MSDN.,it's not convenient enough.
I tried to get controltemplates by adding a reference to the windows.winmd,then getting templates programmatically
like WPF.but I got an Exception,then I looked up the windows.winmd,I found that the Control type didn't have a public constructor,maybe the private constructor caused this Exception.
I also tried to get templates in a UWP App,but I had no
classes to serialize and deserialize the ControlTemplate type into Xaml format in UWP.
(And UWP's XamlWriter & Control  behaves differently from the ones in Wpf)

(I feel sorry about my poor English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the style that you can find in your PC when you installed sdk.

The file path is `C:\Program Files[(x86)]\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\{sdk}\Generic`

If you cant find the `Windows Kits` in Program Files that you may find it in Program Files (x86).

My path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic`

I can see the `generic.xaml` file that include all the style.

Or you also can download the [file](http://7xqpl8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/generic.xaml).

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx